# Retrieving a certain array index in an array of objects using a known attribute?

Tags: java, arrays, object, indexing, attributes

Here is some background for my program:
For class, I'm making a fake log in system.
It uses an array of objects each with attributes assigned.
It seems to have a problem when I try to retrieve the object index for the username/password pair.
I want this index number so I can do more with the user object while they are "logged" in.
However, no matter the username password pair , it has issues getting the correct one.

Here is how I am trying to retrieve it:

```
static int getIndex(User[] users, int index, String userID, String userPin)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) 
    {
     if (users[i].getUserID().equals(userID) && users[i].getPassword().equals(userPin)); 
        {
        System.out.print(i);
        index = i;
        }
    }
return index;

}
}
```

I added in a print statement to see what it was doing.
It prints

```
012
```

and sends the last number, in this case 2, out of the method to be used. 
Alternatively, if I tell it to return within the if block, it just sends back 0 regardless of what username I use.

I've also looked around on this site for other solutions, and they all seemed rather similar to what I'm trying to do except some use an array list. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.
I'd like to keep my array of objects as an array of objects if possible or maybe do a quick conversion back and forth if it really needs to be changed.
Ultimately, I'd like to be able to grab the index ( 0, or 1, or 2) depending on whose username and password is entered and return it to be used as the index elsewhere.

Below is the rest of the code, it has a class to use too, but I didn't want to bombard people with code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User[] users = new User[3];
    users[0] = new User();
    users[1] = new User();
    users[2] = new User();

    users[0].setFirstname("Matt");
    users[0].setLastname("Miller");
    users[0].setUserID("aaa");
    users[0].setPassword("111");

    users[1].setFirstname("Susie");
    users[1].setLastname("Smith");
    users[1].setUserID("bbb");
    users[1].setPassword("222");

    users[2].setFirstname("Joe");
    users[2].setLastname("Jones");
    users[2].setUserID("ccc");
    users[2].setPassword("333");

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your user ID");
String userID = userInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter your PIN");
String userPin= userInput.nextLine();
int Index = 0;

Index = getIndex(users, Index, userID, userPin);
System.out.printf("Welcome %s %s\n\n", users[Index].getFirstname(), users[Index].getLastname());
}
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that a semicolon is used to terminate a statement. As pointed out in the answer above, you are putting a semicolon at the end of if block in your getIndex() method.

```
 if (users[i].getUserID().equals(userID) && users[i].getPassword().equals(userPin)); 
//Remove the semicolon.
        {
        System.out.print(i);
        index = i;
        }
```

When you put a semicolon at the end of an if block then that if block becomes futile. It does nothing. A statement that does nothing is called an empty statement.
Refer to the link given below.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html

You could have easily found out the issue if you had debugged it. I also suggest you to use a static code analyzer like FindBugs. It will scan your  files and most of the time it will tell you about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can see there are two mistakes in your code.

1. in getIndex(...) method you have putted ; (semi column) after if.
2. you have used "username" instead if "userID" in if condition.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you can use, in order to avoid errors, is to let java do the work for you!, wich means that your programming errors are minimized because you don't have to worry about to create the logic that java language can handle much better.

Lets do this.

1. Try to use constructor, it will help to mitigate errors and avoid a lot of number of lines of code, for example:

Instead of 4 lines

```
users[0].setFirstname("Matt");
users[0].setLastname("Miller");
users[0].setUserID("aaa");
users[0].setPassword("111");
```

Better way 1 line, means less error

```
users[0]=ew User("Matt","Miller","aaa","111")
```

2. If the target of the solution is to know what is an array, then its ok, but when the code becomes more complex and there are new requirements to group elements or find by other values, then an array will become a nightmare.  Allways try to use Collections!

The users elements will be organized in a better way to do more operations in a very easy way.

This is the users  elements created in a list, again, less code, less error

```
List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(
        new User("Matt","Miller","aaa","111"),
        new User("Susie","Smith","bbb","222"),
        new User("Joe","Jones","ccc","333")
);
```

3. Now the reason why the program didn't work, the semicolon! (;), it happens all the time, including to the expert developers.

Lets avoid errors, again with less code. And this  time using lambdas, so lets java do the work, avoid for loops, so if you need to find and element of the list there are very powerful tools with stream, filter, collect, map, and so on.

This routine also finds users in the same way that getIndex method but in a very efficient way,  that means that probability of typo errors are reduced because it is java language doing the work.

```
userFound = userList.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getUserID().equals(userID) && s.getPassword().equals(userPin))
                .findFirst();
```

4. And now the following example with some modifications of the program and the suggestions listed to make less effort and avoid errors, hope it helps.

The Application

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(
                new User("Matt","Miller","aaa","111"),
                new User("Susie","Smith","bbb","222"),
                new User("Joe","Jones","ccc","333")
        );

        Optional<User> userFound = null;

        String outputMessage = "";

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your user ID");
        final String userID = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your PIN");
        final String userPin= userInput.nextLine();

        userFound = userList.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getUserID().equals(userID) && s.getPassword().equals(userPin))
                .findFirst();

        outputMessage = userFound.isPresent()? String.format("Welcome %s %s\n\n", userFound.get().getFirstname(), userFound.get().getLastname()):"No user found!";

        System.out.println(outputMessage);
    }}
```

The user class

```
class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String userID;

    public User(String firstname, String lastname, String userID, String password) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String password;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```